# Using prototype/lowpro to reorder items on screen. JS not working

Tags: javascript, events, prototypejs, lowpro

Have the following JS included in my HTML:

```
document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
  Event.addBehavior( {
   'a.move-up:click':  function(event) {
        moveUp(this);
        event.stop();

    },
   'a.move-down:click':  function(event) {
        moveDown(this);
        event.stop();
    }
  });
});

function moveUp(element) {

  var questionElement = $(element).up('div.question');
  var preQuestionElement = questionElement.previous('div.question');
  moveElments('up', questionElement , preQuestionElement);
}

function moveDown(element) {
  var questionElement = $(element).up('.question');
  var postQuestionElement = questionElement.next('.question');

  moveElllments('down', questionElement , postQuestionElement);
}

function moveElments(direction, targRow, sibling) {
    var targetParent = targRow.up('div.questions');
    if(direction == 'up'){
      targRow.remove();
      targetParent.insertBefore(targRow, sibling);
    }
    if(direction == 'down'){
      sibling.remove();
      targetParent.insertBefore(sibling, targRow);
    }
}
```

I then have a link that, when clicked, should move a question (enclosed in div.question) up within a parent  (div.questions).

```
<a class="move-up" href="#" style="">Move Up</a>
```

However it does not seem to work. Appears that the Event handler does not see the "click" event...

What is wrong with that code?
Thanks!

Comment: Is `moveElllments` in `moveDown` a typo?

Comment: Yes, it's a typo. Thank you. But it still does not work. I'm trying Daniel's proposed fix without lowpro's addBehaviour

Comment: Daniel, would you mind re-posting you comment. I actually was goign to give you points as it solves my issues without lowpro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not familiar with lowpro, but here's a solution using vanilla Prototype, and attaches your event listeners using `observe`:

```
document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
  $$('a.move-up').observe('click', function(event) {
    moveUp(this);
    event.stop();
  });

  $$('a.move-down').observe('click', function(event) {
    moveDown(this);
    event.stop();
  });
});
```